# Why it needs an extra pair of bracket?

Tags: powershell

The following powershell script

```
"one","two","three" | % { "$(($l++)): $_" }
```

will print

```
1: one
2: two
3: three
```

However, after remove the bracket around `$l++`

```
"one","two","three" | % { "$($l++): $_" }
```

it will print

```
: one
: two
: three
```

Comment: Oh boy you got the community going on this one! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `$l++` is a **voidable statement**. In powershell certain types of
expressions, when used as statements, are not displayed. 
Voidable statements include assignments and the increment/decrement operators. When they are used in an expression, they return a value, but when they’re used as a standalone statement, they return no value. It is very well explained in *Windows Powershell in Action* by *Bruce Payette*:

> The increment and decrement operators were almost not included in PowerShell
>   because they introduced a problem. In languages such as C and C#, when you use
>   one of these operators as a statement:
>   $a++
>   nothing is displayed. This is because statements in C and C# don’t return values. In
>   PowerShell, however, all statements return a value. This led to confusion. People
>   would write scripts like this:

```
$sum=0
$i=0
while ($i -lt 10) { $sum += $i; $i++ }
$sum
```

> and be surprised to see the numbers 1 through 10 displayed. This was because $a++
>   returned a value and PowerShell was displaying the results of every statement. This
>   was so confusing that we almost removed these operators from the language. Then we
>   hit on the idea of a  voidable statement. Basically, this means that certain types of
>   expressions, when used as statements, are not displayed. Voidable statements include
>   assignments and the increment/decrement  operators. When they are used in an
>   expression, they return a value, but when they’re used as a standalone statement, they
>   return no value. Again, this is one of those details that won’t affect how you use PowerShell other than to make it work as you expect. (source: Windows Powershell in Action)

Comment: Best answer of the lot I think :)

Comment: At the Deep Dive, Bruce also mentioned that this is what makes if statements and loops work like they do:  if ($foo = Get-RandomTrueFalse) {"This can run!"}

Answer (score 4):

I believe this was a design decision made by the PowerShell team to avoid surprises due to PowerShell outputting return values.  Many C/C# folks would expect the following function to only output 1 not @(0,1).

```
function foo {
  $i = 0
  $i++
  $i
}
```

So the statement form `$i++` doesn't output the value of $i before it is incremented. If you want that behavior, PowerShell allows you to get that behavior by putting the increment (or decrement) statement directly inside an expression e.g.:

```
function foo {
  $i = 0
  ($i++)
  $i
}
```

This will output @(0,1).

Bruce Payette discusses this in Chapter 5 of [Windows PowerShell in Action 2nd Edition](http://www.manning.com/payette2/).  The increment and decrement operators are "voidable statements".  Quoting from the book:

> Basically, this means that certain types of expressions, when used as
>   statements, are not displayed. Voidable statements include assignment
>   statements and the increment/decrement operators. When increment and
>   decrement are used in an expression, they return a value, but when
>   they’re used as a standalone statement, they return no value.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `$l++` doesn't return anything, :

```
$l = 0
$l++   #nothing
$l #gives 1
$l++   #nothing
($l++)  #gives 2
```

This is done so that there is no confusion when you are returning to pipeline. Effectively,

`$l++` is `$l = $l+ 1`, so it doesn't return anything.

What you want to see is `$l = $l + 1; $l`, which is why you have to do `($l++)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two tasks it needs to do:

1. Execute `$l++` (increment the variable) which happens on the inner parenthesis
2. Retrieve `$l`'s value which happens in the outer parenthesis.

Here is a illustration of this:

```
$l = 0
"$($l++ ; $l)"
```

Outputs: `1` where

```
$l = 0
"$($l++)"
```

Doesn't output anything.

In order to receive output I need two statements inside the sub-expression. Otherwise the only thing that happens is that `$l` is incremented but its value is not retrieved.