# Why do parentheses cause assignment to produce a result?

Tags: powershell

Consider this bit of PowerShell:

```
PS> $x = 'y'
PS> ($x = 'y')
y
```

Why does adding the parens cause the value to get printed?

**EDIT:** Some more interesting cases:

```
 PS> $z = ($x = 'y')
 PS> $z
 y
 PS> $( $x = $y )
 PS> $z = $( $x = $y )
 PS> $z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parentheses tell the shell to evaluate the value within the parentheses first then print the result. in your first command, it's assignment; However, the second is a command that will be evaluated and print the result, namely 'y'

update

```
PS> $z = ($x = 'y') # assignment, no print , ($x = 'y') returns 'y'
PS> $z    
y
PS> $( $x = $y ) # this is a voidable expression whose result is discarded when used directly as a statement. so, $( $x = $y ) -eq $null
PS> $z = $( $x = $y ) # same to above
PS> $z
```

"PowerShell in Action" states difference between the subexpression construct and simple parentheses is how voidable statements are treated. ++,--,+=,-= operations are treated as voidable statement either.

In simple parentheses (), voidable statements is not discarded, but in subexpression $(), they are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions with side effects don't normally return their result when used as a statement. For example:

```
PS> $x = $a++
```

Clearly, `$a++` must have a value for this to work. However:

```
PS> if (...) $a++
```

you don't want this to print out the value of `$a`. So the result is discarded.

Grouping parentheses override this behavior, and force the result to be returned to the pipeline, even if it's voidable:

```
PS> ($x = 'y')
'y'
```

On the other hand, to void a non-voidable expression, either cast it to `void` or pipe it to `Out-Null`:

```
PS> mkdir Foo | Out-Null
PS> [void](mkdir Bar)
```

## Resources

SO question *[Why it needs an extra pair of bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978954/why-it-needs-an-extra-pair-of-bracket)*

The [Windows PowerShell Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) - *7.1.1 Grouping parentheses*, but they don't use the "voidable expression" terminology.

Blog post *[PowerShell ABC's - V is for Voidable Statements](https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/joe/archive/2009/01/23/powershell-abcs---v-is-for-voidable-statements.aspx)*

Comment: "voidable expression" is used by 'PowerShell in Action', whose author is in charge of powershell in MS. I just copied it. :-)

Comment: Link for [PowerShell ABC's - V is for Voidable Statements](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/powershell-abcs-v-is-for-voidable-statements) has changed.